Iterate from start to end date across years
I am trying to print dates using a for loop. The user inputs a start date and an end date, and the system prints dd/mm for each day between (and including) those dates into adjacent columns on a sheet.
The code works for dates of the same year.
When the dates are in different years (e.g. 16/12/24 - 15/1/25) the for loop never ends.
Examples in the comments with "//" between each example.
start_date = DateValue(InputBox("Please enter the starting date of the new pay cycle in d/m/yy format.", "Paycycle Start Date")) ' 16/7/24 // 16/12/24
end_date = DateValue(InputBox("Please enter the end date of the new pay cycle in d/m/yy format.", "Paycycle End Date")) ' 15/8/24 // 15/1/25

MsgBox DateDiff("d", start_date, end_date) ' 30 // 30 (as expected for both)

Set active_archive = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rota Builder"))

hc_date_headers = 2 ' counting variable to print dates in next column

For printing_dates = start_date To end_date
    printing_dates = Format(printing_dates, "dd/mm") 
    MsgBox printing_dates ' to prevent infinite loop.
    With active_archive.Cells(3, hc_date_headers)
        .Value = DateValue(printing_dates)
        .Font.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
    End With
    ' additional irrelevant code
    hc_date_headers = hc_date_headers + 1
Next ' stops once it reaches 15/8/24 // runs until I ctrl break.

I thought of DateDiff to set the for loop to be between two integers. It does work from the little trial run I have done. I'd have to reformat a painful amount of code, because I use hc_date_headers as a dynamic variable to create another table next to the one I create in this loop.

This line is problematic:
printing_dates = Format(printing_dates, "dd/mm") 

Here's a simple example why:
Sub Oops()
    Dim d As Date
    d = Format("1/1/2025", "dd/mm")
    Debug.Print d ' Returns 1/1/2024 !!
End Sub

You create an infinite loop because printing_dates now always refers to a date in the current year.

That makes sense! I needed that part so it can print properly since I don't need the years, but I think I've found a decent workaround that isn't too much hassle. Thank you!

Happy to help. Good practice is not to modify the iterator. So, you could use another variable, or just use Format directly without assigning to a variable. Note that there's a difference between a Date and its formatted representation.

I ended up doing exactly what BigBen suggested and created another variable for the for loop.
start_date = DateValue(InputBox("Please enter the starting date of the new pay 
cycle in d/m/yy format.", "Paycycle Start Date")) 
end_date = DateValue(InputBox("Please enter the end date of the new pay cycle 
in d/m/yy format.", "Paycycle End Date")) 

Set active_archive = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rota Builder"))

printing_dates = start_date
hc_date_headers = 2

For column_counter = 1 To DateDiff("d", start_date, end_date) + 1
    printing_dates = Format(printing_dates, "dd/mm")
    With active_archive.Cells(3, hc_date_headers)
        .Value = DateValue(printing_dates)
        .Font.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218)
    End With

    hc_date_headers = hc_date_headers + 1
    printing_dates = DateAdd("d",1,printing_dates)
Next

Since I don't actually output the year, it doesn't matter if format changes the year to be 2024, as printing_dates is formatted after DateDiff is used.
Surprisingly a quick fix! Thanks so much :D

Side note: perhaps consider using .NumberFormat = "dd/mm" to apply dd/mm formatting to the cell, instead of messing with Format in the loop.

Populate Consecutive Dates in Row

Main
Sub BuildSheet()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Build Sheet"

    ' Define constants.

    ' Dates Input
    Const START_PROMPT As String = _
        "Please enter the start date of the new paycycle in d/m/yy format."
    Const START_TITLE As String = "Paycycle Start Date"
    Const END_PROMPT As String = _
        "Please enter the end date of the new paycycle in d/m/yy format."
    Const END_TITLE As String = "Paycycle End Date"
    ' Dates Misc.
    Const DATES_AFTER_SHEET_NAME As String = "Rota Builder"
    Const DATES_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B3"
    Const DATE_FORMAT As String = "dd/mm" ' if default is not '/', use "dd\/mm"
    Dim DATES_INTERIOR_COLOR As Long: DATES_INTERIOR_COLOR = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' dark
    Dim DATES_FONT_COLOR As Long: DATES_FONT_COLOR = RGB(226, 239, 218) ' light
    Const DATES_FONT_BOLD As Boolean = True
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If this is the workbook containing this code, use 'Set wb = ThisWorkbook'
    ' and remove the following 'If' statement.
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no active workbook!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Return the dates in a 1D one-based array.
    
    Dim StartDate As Date: StartDate = RetrieveDate(START_PROMPT, START_TITLE)
    If StartDate = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim EndDate As Date: EndDate = RetrieveDate(END_PROMPT, END_TITLE)
    If EndDate = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim DaysCount As Long: DaysCount = EndDate - StartDate + 1
    
    If DaysCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "The start date """ & StartDate _
            & """ is greater than the end date """ & EndDate & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim DaysData() As Date: ReDim DaysData(1 To DaysCount)
    
    Dim DayDate As Date: DayDate = StartDate
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To DaysCount
        DaysData(c) = DayDate
        DayDate = DayDate + 1
    Next c
    
    ' Return the dates from the array in a new worksheet.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:
    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(DATES_AFTER_SHEET_NAME))
    
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = ws.Range(DATES_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(, DaysCount)
    
    ' Format.
    drg.NumberFormat = DATE_FORMAT
    drg.Interior.Color = DATES_INTERIOR_COLOR
    drg.Font.Color = DATES_FONT_COLOR
    drg.Font.Bold = DATES_FONT_BOLD
    ' Copy.
    drg.Value = DaysData
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Dates populated.", vbInformation

    ' The first cell of the other table (to the right) can be referenced
    ' with 'dfcell.Offset(, DaysCount + 1)' to have an empty column in-between.

End Sub

Help
Function RetrieveDate( _
    ByVal Prompt As String, _
    ByVal Title As String) _
As Date

    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Retrieve Date"
    
    Dim InputString As String: InputString = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

    Dim ResultDate As Date
    On Error Resume Next
        ResultDate = DateValue(InputString)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ResultDate = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The string """ & InputString & """ doesn't represent " _
            & "a valid date!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    RetrieveDate = ResultDate

End Function


Your code is miles beyond my skill set at the moment, I only started learning vba around 60 days ago so a lot of this is going over my head. I look forward to coming back to this down the line to see if it makes sense to me eventually haha. Thank you for helping!
